# Snmp Walk in Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, snmp

When i snmpWalk an ip, it takes 5 second. But if i send the snmpWalk request in a for loop, walk time goes up. Is there any good practice about using snmp in a multithread way or just use ExecutorService? I used ExecutorService and it also slows down the snmp requests when the thread count is more. May be there is something wrong with my approach, i don't know. I will appricate it if there will be any other idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you edit your post to show us some of your code?  Can you edit your post to expand on what you mean by for-loop takes more time.  Do you mean forking threads?  Do you know if the device you are querying supports multiple concurrent requests or are you hitting multiple devices?

Comment: Actually i didnt mean forking threads, only a for loop making request sequentially. So there is no issue about the device supporting multiple requests.
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
 snmpwalk();

Comment: Even with this "for" code, requests slow more and more with each step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter how many snmpwalks you will use if SNMP agent responds in single-threaded, sequenced mode. Overloading the agent with requests will only decrease respond time. So, if you are able to enable SNMP agent to work in multi-threaded way, do it and check what is the speedup factor, if any...

You may speed-up walk command by using SNMP in version 2 or 3 and snmpbulkwalk. This approach reduces a network traffic due to a bulk mode - I would expect some speed-up using this approach.

Comment: Nice points. I tried some multi-thread approaches but the result was same. My question is; what is snmpBulkWalk? I am aware of getBulk but how can i implement a bulk walk? I don't know much about bulks.

Comment: So, SNMP snmpBulkWalk is a sequence of getBulks treated as a single command. If you are using NET-SNMP framework, you have the snmpbulkwalk command out of the box, see: [man page](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpbulkwalk.html). To use snmpBulkWalk, you need SNMPv2c at least. If you compare snmpWalk and snmpBulkWalk, you will notice that snmpBulkWalk is faster. Take a look also on options for configuring non-repeaters and max-repeaters (in short those options controls amount of data returned) - if you may use NET-SNMP, then those options are -Cn <value> and -Cr <value>. See the man page.

Comment: I am using snmp4j. Maybe i can implement my swmpbulkwalk with using snmpBulkGets. Thanks for the tip.